# VS2013 external LOG file

Tags: windows

I'm new at Visual Studio and would like to know how to make LOG files out of an information(int) from my code.

As you can see below, my code gets the numberPeopleWay1 and numberPeopleWay2. This information is stored in a pic.

I would like to know how can I print this information into a external LOG file.

Ex:

```
    _ctr.ExtractNumberPeople(
                           (Bitmap)frame,ctrOptions,
                           ref _numberPeopleWay1,
                           ref _numberPeopleWay2
     );
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) As posted your question is lacking so much information, that it's quite impossible to provide a good answer. It's not even clear what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some library e.g [Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or similar. They are meant for logging purpose only.

Here is a simple tutorial [log-net-Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial)